# Mapping Values in Qlikview

Tags: mapping, qlikview

In Qlikview, I have an excel sheet that I use to map USERNAME to a TEAM value. But everytime I refresh the dashboard, new USERNAME values come up and since they are not in the excel sheet, these USERNAME values show up as their own value in the TEAM column. How would I make it so that any USERNAME that is not in the excel sheet shows up as 'Unidentified' or another value under the TEAM column instead of showing up as their own separate value?

Answer (score 11):

First of all when posting question here if possible always include the source code so everybody will have more clear picture about your problem. Just saying.

On the topic ...

Use the `mapping load` in this case with supplying the third parameter. For example:

```
TeamMapping:
Mapping  
Load
  UserName,
  Team
From
  [User_to_Team_Mapping.xlsx] (ooxml, embedded labels, table is [Sheet1])
; 

Transactions:
Load 
  Id,
  Amount,
  ApplyMap( 'TeamMapping', User, 'Unidentified') as Team
From
  Transactions.qvd (qvd)
;
```

The third parameter in `ApplyMap` is the default string value when mapping value was not found in the mapping table (`TeamMapping`)